# java adding cdata to xml string

Tags: java, xml, cdata

I need to add CDATA to xml string for sign it with certificate.

String looks like:

```
<SignedContent>someparametres</SignedContent>
```

Result must be like:

```
<![CDATA[<SignedContent>someparametres</SignedContent>]]>
```

How can i do this? Pls help

P.S. Xml string has only one row (removed all tabs, all spaces, BOM)

Comment: What XML API are you using?

Comment: Does it really have to be CDATA? could the content simply be encoded for use within xml (i.e. &lt;SignedContent&gt;someparameters&lt;/SignedContent&gt;)?

Comment: @BrettOkken yes, it must be CDATA

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you just want:

```
Node cdata = doc.createCDATASection(text);
parentElement.appendChild(cdata);
```

Comment: How can i add cdata to xml where root element is SignedContent. If i add cdata like u wrote, it will be looks like `<SignedContent><![CDATA[someparameters]]></SignedContent>`.

Comment: @bakash_erni: It's not clear what you mean. What you've shown in your question is CDATA whose content *is* SignedContent. In other words, you should be taking your SignedContent element, converting that to text, creating a CDATASection from that, and adding it to some other node. You can't have an XML document whose root node is itself CDATA.

Answer (score 9):

This post may be hold but i feel i should respond, this may help someone else.

```
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(SignedContent.class);
        Marshaller marshallerObj = context.createMarshaller();
        marshallerObj.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        marshallerObj.marshal(signedContentObj, sw);
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setValidating(true);
        factory.setExpandEntityReferences(false);
        Document doc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
        doc.createCDATASection(sw.toString()).getData();
```

You can play around from here...

Comment: Oops,my response is in JAVA, since the question did not specify any language

Answer (score -5):

Use Javas `+` operator:

```
"<![CDATA[" + "<SignedContent>someparametres</SignedContent>" + "]]>"
```

Comment: *Please* don't start manipulating XML documents using string operations. Recipe for failure.

Comment: @JonSkeet CDATA contains just character data. It is nothing more than a string.

Comment: Good luck with that if the text you want to represent happens to include `]]>`. I'd expect an XML API to make that error clear immediately, rather than giving you an invalid XML document. Bypassing the XML model and using strings is pretty much *always* a bad idea.

Comment: @JonSkeet [CDATA sections cannot nest.](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-cdata-sect)

Comment: Indeed. So will your approach highlight that problem immediately, or create an invalid doc? The latter, I believe - whereas by using an XML API, you can get validation as you construct the doc, making it easier to find problems.